# Неожидаемо работает margin при float

Tags: html, css

[image: Демонстрация проблемы]

Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой, хотелось бы, чтобы был отступ 30px от верхних элементов, но увы margin с применением float сработал не так, как я ожидал. Что предложите сделать?
Вот код:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

header, section, aside, footer {
    background: rgb(72, 165, 49);
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

section {
    float: left;
    width: 60%
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}

.main {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <header></header>
        <section></section>
        <aside></aside>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень частая проблема. Решается через оборачивание двух элементов с float в специальный блок clearfix

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

header, section, aside, footer {
    background: rgb(72, 165, 49);
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

section {
    float: left;
    width: 60%
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}

.main {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.clearfix::after{
   content:'';
   clear: both;
   display:table;
}
footer {
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <header></header>
        <div class="clearfix">
           <section></section>
           <aside></aside>
        </div>
        
        <footer></footer>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```